# FormatException in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart

i'm trying to send data to my server using post http method. Backend works perfectly (test made with postman) but i'm getting this error in flutter!

here is my code:

```
Future<MesureModel?> postMeasurement(String description) async {
    final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('${baseUrl}/api/v1/measurements/create'),
        body: {"description": description});
    var data = response.body;
    return MesureModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }
```

and here is my model:

```
List<MesureModel> mesureModelFromJson(String str) => List<MesureModel>.from(
    json.decode(str).map((x) => MesureModel.fromJson(x)));

String mesuretModelToJson(List<MesureModel> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class MesureModel {
  MesureModel(
      {required this.measurement_id,
      required this.measured_value,
      required this.taken_by,
      required this.param_name,
      required this.description});

  int measurement_id;
  double measured_value;
  String taken_by;
  String param_name;
  String description;

  factory MesureModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MesureModel(
      measurement_id: json["measurement_id"],
      measured_value: json["measured_value"],
      taken_by: json["taken_by"],
      param_name: json["param_name"],
      description: json["description"]);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "measurement_id": measurement_id,
        "measured_value": measured_value,
        "taken_by": taken_by,
        "param_name": param_name,
        "description": description
      };
}
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<MesureModel?> postMeasurement(String description) async {
final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('${baseUrl}/api/v1/measurements/create'),
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
    body: json.encode({"input_description": description}));
var data = response.body;
return MesureModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
}
```

Json encode the body before sending

Comment: it fixed the error, but it's sending 'undefined' as a value to the db table! still figuring out the reason

Comment: When you call the postMeasurement method are you passing the description too?

Comment: absolutely, passing inside of it the DescriptionController.text, i'm just trying to save an input into my database! I don't know what's wrong..

Comment: Try printing the description in this method.. i think you would have not assigned the controller to the text field

Comment: this is the body of the post method read from console: {"description========================":"this is a test"}
which is getting the data but not sending it to the server

Comment: The description key has these === also? What's the key required by the api?

Comment: no I just print it to point out the message in the console! lemme just double check the api key

Comment: You can also try and add headers. Edited my answer

Comment: Even with the modifications, it still sends an 'undefined' value which is pretty weird! I made sure it's even the same api key in postman! what do you think it could be?

Comment: Is it working from postman? If yes can you add a screenshot of postman api call and it's response please?

Comment: Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/GMOmAyQ

Comment: Key is input_description. Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You should specify `Content-Type` and encode payload

```
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('${baseUrl}/api/v1/measurements/create'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      "description": description,
    }),
  );

  var data = response.body;
  return MesureModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
```